# Can a company publish under an Individual iphone developer license

Tags: iphone, licensing

I own a very small legally registered company that comprise of a team of 3. I purchased an individual license early this August under my personal name. We intend to publish our first product this september under my license but have our company name and website displayed in the product. Is this allowed by Apple? 
Can I publish a product under an individual license and display my company name in it?

Comment: This question is off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1):

you can, but the name that will be shown will be the one who it belongs to.

Comment: I think that will be fine with me for our first release. Then I can reapply for a company account later. I was just worried if Apple might have a problem with us branding the game with the company name under indie license

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer your personal (individual) account, to a team (company) account. You will need to provide Apple with legal paperwork and trademark information regarding your company.

Answer (score 0):

I just spoke with apple and they confirmed I could put my company details in the game if I want to just that my personal name will be displayed on the appstore which I'm cool with. :)

Answer (score -1):

You could try to transfer you personal license to your company and re-apply for the personal again. Don't know if Apple will do this but I would call and at least find out.

Comment: So does it mean i could have created the individual license with a company name?

Comment: again I would call Apple to clarify this. Maybe there is just an upgrade charge or something. As I see on the Apple website: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/apply.html there are two types of license and unless your a mega corp or someone developing for one you should have the correct one. I'm just stating that Apple (If you call them) might change the name on the account from your personal to your company. You might be able to do this under the user settings as well (Never checked). Post back ;)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/contact/ maybe send them the question?